# Call setTimeout at Firebase Cloud Functions onCreate

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using following code in order to call a function with setTimeout,
but I'm not really into JS and Firebase Cloud Functions.

However my logs are showing following error:
"Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"
"Exception from a finished function: Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string."

This is my code:

```
function updateDoc(id) {
    admin.firestore().collection('Orders').doc(id).update({status: 2}).then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });
}

exports.updateField = functions.firestore
    .document('/Orders/{id}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const id = context.params.id;
      setTimeout(updateDoc.bind(id), 30000) 
    });
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- You should pass the id as a "simple" argument when calling the `updateDoc()`method.
- You need to return a Promise or a value in your Cloud Function to indicate to the Cloud Function platform that the Cloud Function has completed. You'll find more details in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and in this [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/).

In addition, using `setTimeout` in a Cloud Function shall be done with care, see these [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%20setTimeout%20Cloud%20Function). You could probably re-architect your solution in order to avoid the `setTimeout`. If you share more info on why you use it, the community may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason why I need that functionality is following: I want to have a status indicator for inserts the user makes. So giving a feedback how long the insert already exists and displaying colors like 5min ago: change document field to 1 -> Displaying yellow color, 10min ago: change document field to 2 -> Displaying red color. The only thing I need for this is a timer in the background counting the time and change some data after a specific amount of time from when a insert was created.